# Print the array as the array itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to print this array as an array itself in a div like this:

`array = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]]`

Here is what I have currently:

```js
var a = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]];


document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML= "array = " + a
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @MarkSkelton why change the congenial tone of the original by changing, "Friends, how should I do this?"  Just because that's not how you write/speak does not mean it must be changed.  Nothing is gained by that edit and personally I appreciated the friendly tone of the unedited question.

Comment: @Paul As I understand, extra fluff in questions (e.g. Hi, Thanks, etc.) is not something that Stack Overflow encourages.  This post on meta has some more info about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts.  I recognize that it is talking more about the start and end of a post, but I think the principles still apply.

Comment: @MarkSkelton You're not wrong but if OP had written "How should I do this?" would it need to be changed?  What about "JavaScript experts, how should I do this?"?  Those are rhetorical questions to illustrate how I see the phraseology.  I agree that starting the question with "Hello, friends!" would be considered "fluff" but given it is a new user's first question I would allow more latitude even in that case and instead leave a comment saying, "Welcome to SO! In future questions...".  We can agree to disagree, it's not a big deal.  Happy New Year!

Comment: @Paul You definitely make good points and I appreciate your thoughts and opinions.  I'll definitely keep this in mind as I edit future questions.  Happy New Year to you as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to produce the result you are expecting.

```js
var a = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]];


document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML= "array = " + JSON.stringify(a)
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for this and you should also use `pre` tag in addition to it to make it look good

```js
const json = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]];


document.querySelector("#json").innerHTML= "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) + "</pre>"
```

```html
<div id="json"></div>
```